# How to make AND operator in C# linq?

Tags: c#, linq

```
IEnumerable<WireUsrTgInfo> lstWireData = 
    (from var in lstWireUsrTgInfo
     where var.bWireData == true && var.bWireData == false --> This is not working
     select var).AsEnumerable<WireUsrTgInfo>();
```

How to do this ...

Comment: Don't use `var` it is confusing and a keyword.

Comment: That's it :) `var lstWireData = Enumerable.Empty<WireUsrTgInfo>();`

Comment: You don't need the enclosing brackets and the `AsEnumerable<WireUsrTgInfo>()` at the end. The result would be the same.

Comment: your where clause will always be false since you are in essence doing var.bWireData != var.bWireData which of course will always be false

Answer (score 5):

according to the code provided

```
var.bWireData == true && var.bWireData == false
```

it can not work, as the same variable can not *contemporary* be equal to both oposite values.

if you need parametrize this, you can do it like :

```
bool expectedValue = true; //OR False
IEnumerable<WireUsrTgInfo> lstWireData = (from var in lstWireUsrTgInfo
            where var.bWireData == expectedValue
            select var).AsEnumerable<WireUsrTgInfo>();
```

**EDIT**

And don't use `var` in the query, it's contextual (as mantioned by Monkieboy) `C#` keyword. To be clear: you **can** use it, but you **have to** avoid doing that as it creates confusion.

Comment: `var` is not reserved but it is a `contextual` keyword; you are correct it shouldn't be used but for confusion issues. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx

Comment: @Monkieboy: sure you **can** use it, but you **have not** do that, for confusion issue.

Comment: Yes that clarifies further but to call it a 'reserved' keyword is technically wrong. It is a 'contextual' keyword. It is a little frustrating that it can be used as a variable name because it would make life easier if it was highlighted (as a warning) during compilation like a true 'reserved' keyword.

Answer (score 3):

`bWireData` cannot both be true AND false. There's a flaw in your logic.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers stated, your filter condition is wrong. But there is something else I want to add:

Don't compare boolean data with `true` or `false`. Boolean data is actually an answer to question is it `true` or not.

```
var query = from info in lstWireUsrTgInfo
            where info.bWireData // selects data which is true
            select info;
```

Also `var` is a keyword;

Also do not use prefixes in variable names (consider better naming instead - `HasWireData`, `wireUserTagInfos`).

Answer (score 0):

This will never work:  `WHERE bWireData == true && bWireData == false` is illogical be cause bWireData can't be both true and false at the same time.

`var` is a keyword and to avoid confusion should therefor not be used as a name for a variable.

Comment: Var actually can be used there, I thought the same thing. Try it.

Comment: Didn't knew about it, in other languages you can't do that right?

Comment: remove the word 'reserved', as it is a keyword but not reserved.

Answer (score 0):

&& is the correct operator. However, as other posters have noted, your query as it stands is equivalent to saying "Make me happy if Obama is president and Obama is not president". Basically you have set up a contradiction, which will always evaluate to false and thus return no results. As an aside, you may be interested to learn that && is a conditional-and, meaning that the second term is only evaluated if the first term is true, thus saving the processing of second term if the result is inevitably false anyway.